# How can I fix this issue in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code, the purpose is to create read, and add to JSON file in Ruby
I will copy the code and the error am getting down here

game_module.rb

```
    require 'json'
require_relative '../classes/game'
require 'date'

def load_games
    data = []
    file = './json_files/games.json'
    if File.exist?(file)
      JSON.parse(File.read(file)).each do |game|
        publish_date = game['publish_date'] ? Date.parse(game['publish_date']) : nil
        last_played_at = game['last_played_date'] ? Date.parse(game['last_played_date']) : nil
        data.push(Game.new(publish_date, game['multiplayer'], last_played_at, archived: game['archived']))
      end
    else
      File.write('./json_files/games.json', [])
    end
  
    data
  end  

  def create_game
    data = []
    @games.each do |game|
      data.push(game.publish_date, game.multiplayer, game.last_played_date, archived: game.archived)
    end
    File.write('./json_files/games.json', JSON.generate(data))
  end
```

game.rb file

```
    require_relative './items'
require 'date'

class Game < Item
  attr_accessor :multiplayer, :last_played_date

  def initialize(date, multiplayer, last_played_date, archived: false, id: nil)
    super(id, date, archived: archived)
    @multiplayer = multiplayer
    @last_played_date = Date.parse(last_played_date)
  end

  def can_be_archived?
    current_date = Date.today
    super && (current_date.year - @last_played_date.year) > 2
  end
end
```

json file

```
[{"publish_date":"2022-01-01", "multiplayer": false, "last_played_date": "2021-12-31","archived": false}]
```

the error text

```
no implicit conversion of Date into String (TypeError)

 from /home/shaker/Desktop/microverse - backend /Ruby-Catalog-of-my-things/src/classes/items.rb:8:in `initialize'
        from /home/shaker/Desktop/microverse - backend /Ruby-Catalog-of-my-things/src/classes/game.rb:8:in `initialize'
        from /home/shaker/Desktop/microverse - backend /Ruby-Catalog-of-my-things/src/modules/game_module.rb:12:in `new'
        from /home/shaker/Desktop/microverse - backend /Ruby-Catalog-of-my-things/src/modules/game_module.rb:12:in `block in load_games'
        from /home/shaker/Desktop/microverse - backend /Ruby-Catalog-of-my-things/src/modules/game_module.rb:9:in `each'
        from /home/shaker/Desktop/microverse - backend /Ruby-Catalog-of-my-things/src/modules/game_module.rb:9:in `load_games'
        from /home/shaker/Desktop/microverse - backend /Ruby-Catalog-of-my-things/app.rb:22:in `<class:App>'
        from /home/shaker/Desktop/microverse - backend /Ruby-Catalog-of-my-things/app.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from main.rb:1:in `require_relative'
        from main.rb:1:in `<main>
```

Comment: `Date.parse` is expecting a `String` but when JSON parses your data the dates are converted to `Date` objects, which means there is no reason to parse them again e.g. `Date.parse(game['publish_date'])`, so `publish_date = game['publish_date']` would work fine.

Comment: how would you suggest my code to look like? without the parsing should it be lilke this 
        data.push(Game.new(game['publish_date'], game['multiplayer'], game['last_played_at'], archived: game['archived']))

Comment: What it *should* look like is part preferential and part off Topic for SO but what you have proposed will work and will be functionally equivalent to your desired outcome.